# Redirect Wordpress Site to react site

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have developed react site which depends on rest api by wordpress. I have placed wordpress in a subdomain and placed react site in main domain. Now I would like to redirect all links from wordpress site to react site except for /wp-admin an /wp-json/* links.

How I can achive this?

Is there any plugin for wordprees?

And I have tried password protecting the subdomain but the issue is that, doing so won't allow me to access the api. 
What should be my approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the filter?

Example:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', function ($post_link, $post) {
  // edit the link
  $post_link = 'https://my.custom.site';
  return $post_link;
}, 999, 4);
```

Comment: I want to redirect my entire wp site to react site not just post links

Comment: @JamilurRahman I'm not sur to understand what you want. You mean that you would like that users going to subdomain.domain.com/contact per example get redirected automatically on domain.com/contact? If yes, take a look at htaccess https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-